# google map polyline infowindow

Tags: google-maps, polyline

As continuation to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31055752/google-map-multiple-polyline), i trying to add the respective json object name to infowindow content as,

```
 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content:i
  });
```

Which is given in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/whop1j4e/16/) but it displays only the name of last object. I also tried with `return` function as

```
google.maps.event.addListener(poly, 'click', (function(event, (poly, i)) {
    return function() {
  infowindow.open(map);
  infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
    }
  })(poly, i));
```

but no use ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/whop1j4e/17/)). How can I achieve it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple polylines and infowindows with Google Maps V3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068110/multiple-polylines-and-infowindows-with-google-maps-v3)

Comment: Not working the solution in above link.  http://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/whop1j4e/18/

Comment: Did you see the javascript error in [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/whop1j4e/17/) `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (`

Comment: Or the javascript error in [the fiddle in your comment](http://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/whop1j4e/18/): `Uncaught ReferenceError: infowindow is not defined`

Comment: No way.. http://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/whop1j4e/19/

Comment: Javascript is case sensitive, infoWindow is not the same as infowindow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said "But all brackets are correctly closed.".  This is not correct (you have an extra set of parentheses in the function definition):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(poly, 'click', (function(event, (poly, i)) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.open(map);
      infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
    }
  })(poly, i));
```

The `event` argument belongs to the returned function, and you only need closure on the polygon (`poly`) and the loop index (`i`):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(poly, 'click', (function (poly, i) {
    return function (event) {
        infowindow.setContent(""+i);
        infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
        infowindow.open(map);
    };
})(poly, i));
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/whop1j4e/20/)